# How can i add Custom Attributes to my Azure AD tenant members (Not B2C users)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, system-administration

I have an Azure AD tenant and I am looking for a way to include extra attributes while creating members within my organization. I have poked around the interface and can't find a way to achieve this on the Azure portal. From my findings, I can see tones of documentation and blog posts on how to achieve this using the B2C feature and graph API for external customers. However, this does not meet my requirements.

I believe this is a basic requirement that should be possible on Azure AD. Can someone please point me to the right documentation to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure portal doesn't provide such a feature but we can archive this using Microsoft Graph API: [Create extensionProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-extensionproperty?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You need to specify the `targetObjects` as "User".

An example (you can use any of your app registrations for `{object id of the app registration}`):

```
Post https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{object id of the app registration}/extensionProperties

{"name":"customAttribute","dataType":"string","targetObjects":["User"]}
```

It will generate an extension property named `extension_{client id of the app registration without "-"}_customAttribute`.

Then you can update the extension property for a user:

```
Patch https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}

{"extension_{client id of the Azure AD application without "-"}_customAttribute":"value"}
```

Comment: Thanks @Allen Wu, I do appreciate this. However, the business requirements here does not require any third party application integration. I would like to add those extra properties to the AD member users within the organization themselves and not external customers. Could it be that Azure AD actually does not support this feature?

Comment: @Needium Maybe you have a misunderstanding. I didn't mention "third party application integration".  Microsoft graph itself is used in conjunction with AAD. If you don't want to develop your own web app, you can use the official tool [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). And it adds those extra properties to the AD member users, not external customers.

Comment: Thanks @Allen, So I figured out you were right, I can use the graph API to set custom properties. The provided link was helpful. However, I was more interested in setting those custom properties from the Azure Portal UI and but later reading it from a Powershell script. Apparently, there is currently no support to create them from the UI. Thanks